# Mailgun Email rejected by some providers

Tags: dns, smtp, mailgun

I am trying to send emails through MailGun APIs and it was working fine until we noticed some emails were rejected by Orange.fr . I assume it could be the case for other providers, but Gmail is working fine for instance.

Error I see in MailGun admin panel is the following:

> Failed: postmaster@mg.lesjardinsdelariviere.com → m****ou@orange.fr 'Subject' Server response: 501 5.1.0 Emetteur invalide. Invalid Sender. OFR003_405 [405]

I am sending those emails from no-reply@lesjardinsdelariviere.com and in Gmail they appear to be signed & sent by "mg.lesjardinsdelariviere.com"

I had requested my DNS provider to make those changes to verify my MailGun account:

> (type, hostname, value)
>
> TXT mg.lesjardinsdelariviere.com v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all
>
> TXT mx._domainkey.mg.lesjardinsdelariviere.com k=rsa;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC9x/kulF+1LfeDRnrAlDjNBwD7oP7jIcdJ9MhgWASmDh3SJ2t2GT2zmTSKMPt25dtEYNMX2qvXIAq/rmQ4XB15YgBUTUaX/IdJ18bYUulH//BXVq7q8H2J/mWYAcoWnTTecVOUm75CiY6rngtBBw1g+TICnVMq2/HZ0lA047HEhQIDAQAB
>
> (type, priority, value)
>
> MX 10 mxa.mailgun.org
>
> MX 10 mxb.mailgun.org
>
> (type, hostname, value)
>
> CNAME email.mg.lesjardinsdelariviere.com mailgun.org

I tried searching for similar issues and I think there might be something missing in the DNS records but I don't know what... Any help? Thanks!

Comment: check with mailgun about it.

Answer (score 1):

Mailgun is regularly added to spam blacklists because their entire business model is based on sending out huge numbers of emails and these are not always appreciated.

There is nothing you can do about this except change mail providers or complain to mailgun.

If you are truly sending out mail that is "not spam", for example customer invoices or individually written emails to individual people, you can get your own dedicated server from a reputable hosting company, and a clean IP address, and you will have very few delivery problems.